# Codename one set remove Accordion border

Tags: accordion, codenameone

I am working on a codename one application. I need to remove the border for Accordion component. (or) Is there anyway to change the Accordion's border color..
Can someone guide me...

[The black border shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enwWF.jpg)

Comment: Share your source code and show something, so that others can see, what issue you are facing. No one can fix your issues blindly..

Comment: I have added a image to show the border i am talking about

Comment: you need to share your code, use Codepen or JsFiddle or even can do it using SO code snippet editor. ! We need to know, from where the border is coming, or which plugin are you using,, is it really an image or shadow..

Answer (score 1):

In your theme.res, just add a UIID with no border and set this UIID for accordeon.
Otherwise , you can override accordeon UIID and set empty border **like this** : 
[image]

And then uncheck derive and select **border "empty"**
[image]

Comment: can you please elaborate it

Answer (score 0):

To remove(hide) the border of an accordion from the code you can define it's border colour to be the same as the background colour and to be as narrow as possible.

```
    Border border = Border.createCompoundBorder(Border.createLineBorder(1, 0xffffff), Border.createLineBorder(1, 0xffffff), Border.createLineBorder(1, 0xffffff), Border.createLineBorder(1, 0xffffff));

    my_accordion = new Accordion(ifont_keyboard_right, ifont_keyboard_down);
    my_accordion.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffffff);
    my_accordion.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(255);
    my_accordion.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    my_accordion.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
    my_accordion.getAllStyles().setBorder(border);
```